# Double CORS headers with spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: cors, spring-cloud-gateway

How to disable CORS on gateway? I mean really disable, not allow requests from all origins with all methods like you find when searching for "disable gateway CORS" on stackoeverflow or elsewhere.

I have a spring-cloud-gateway in front of a few services which already position response CORS headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and alike) and for some of this services, I can hardly disable CORS (Keycloak for instance).

My problem is spring-cloud-gateway set some of those headers too, which results in duplicate CORS headers and a CORS error in client app. So I'd like to completely disable CORS filters on the gateway (ideally globally but a `filter` configuration to apply to each route would be acceptable too)

Gateway configuration:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-RC2</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.user-proxies</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping=true
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowed-origins=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowed-headers=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].allowed-methods=*
spring.cloud.gateway.globalcors.corsConfigurations.[/**].exposed-headers=*
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/users/**").uri("https://localhost:9443"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/greet/**").uri("https://localhost:9445"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/realms/**").uri("https://localhost:8443"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

When trying to go through the gateway (send all requests to port 8080) with CORS enabled on resource-servers, I get cors Errors and response headers contained doubled CORS headers:
[image: CORS error in Chrome developer tools showing doubled CORS headers in response]

When configured for direct connection (contact resource-servers on ports 9443 and 9445), Angular requests are sucessful.

If I disable CORS in resource-servers (those on ports 9443 and 9445), then CORS headers are not doubled anymore and requests through the gateway are successful (but direct requests fail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to de-duplicate CORS headers on the gateway:

```java
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> brutalCorsFilters) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(p -> p.path("/users/**").filters(brutalCorsFilters).uri("https://localhost:9443"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/greet/**").filters(brutalCorsFilters).uri("https://localhost:9445"))
                .route(p -> p.path("/realms/**").filters(brutalCorsFilters).uri("https://localhost:8443"))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Function<GatewayFilterSpec, UriSpec> brutalCorsFilters() {
        return f -> f
                .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
                .setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
    }
```

With this, CORS configuration can remain active on resource-servers (but will be ignored).

I'd prefer to disable gateway CORS processor and keep resource-servers CORS headers, but at least this is usable.

Comment: I tried to repeat your code. Server-resource left unchanged with cors enabled. And I rewrote GateWay as in your question. But I still get a cors error when sending a Get request to a Server-resource via GateWay

Comment: The properties are important too. Check that you have the same configuration in properties file and in the "brutalCorsFilter". And, off course, be sure that the "brutalCorsFilter" is correctly applied to the route you have CORS issue with (set a breakpoint or a log entry)

Comment: If I add your code to the properties file, I get the error "Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level." in Resource-server

Comment: It is likely that you now have a different issue. Does the direct call work (what happens if you configure the client to call the internal port of the resource-server instead of the gateway one)?

Comment: Your option worked for me, but only after I configured cors support on the resource server

Comment: If your read my question carefully, you may note that my problem was precisely how to configure gateway when CORS headers are already set by resource-server.